# Python: How to call member functions a key of a dict when the key is an object?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, key

In the following example, I want to change the `a1` key of `d` in place by calling the `set_x()` function of the class `A`. But I don't see how to access a key in a `dict`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A(object):
  def __init__(self, data=''):
    self.data = data
    self.x = ''
  def set_x(self, x):
    self.x = x
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'A(%s:%s)' % (self.data, self.x)
  def __eq__(self, another):
    return hasattr(another, 'data') and self.data == another.data
  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.data)

a1 = A('foo')
d = {a1: 'foo'}
print d #{A(foo:): 'foo'}
```

I want to change `d`, so that `d` will print as `{A(foo:word): 'foo'}`. Of course, the following does not work. Also I don't want to reassign the same values. Does anybody know a way to modify a key in place by the calling the key's member function? Thanks.

```
a2 = A('foo')
a2.set_x('xxxx')
d[a2]='foo'
print d
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the object itself, and modify it there.

Take a look at this console session:

```
>>> a = A("foo")
>>> d = {a:10}
>>> d
{A(foo:): 10}
>>> a.set_x('word')
>>> d
{A(foo:word): 10}
```

You can also get the key-value pair from `dict.items()`:

```
a, v = d.items()[0]
a.set_x("word")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the reference to the object and modify it. If you can't keep a reference to the key object, you can still iterate over the dict using `for k, v in d.items():` and then use the value to know which key you have (although this is somewhat backward in how to use a dict and highly ineficient)

```
a1 = A('foo')
d = {a1: 'foo'}
print(d) # {A(foo:): 'foo'}
a1.set_x('hello')
print(d) # {A(foo:hello): 'foo'}
```